# How to securely save credentials into a mobile application?

Tags: web-services, security, mobile

I develop iOS and Android mobile applications using Xamarin but my question is not linked to the technology.

In few applications, I want to call a webservice that I'm developping too. In a method of this webservice, both 'login' and 'password' are required to perform the method operation.

This 'login' and 'password' are not linked to a user but are common to the entire application.

So the question is : how to securely save these login information into the application ?

Is there a well-know architecture that solves the hard-coded information problem ?

Answer (score 1):

Any credentials that are stored in the app can be exposed by the user. In the case of Android, they can completely decompile your app and easily retrieve them.

If the connection to the server does not utilize SSL, they can be easily sniffed off the network.

Seriously, anybody who wants the credentials will get them, so don't worry about concealing them. In essence, you have a public API.

There are some pitfalls and it takes extra time to manage a public API.

Many public APIs still track by IP address and implement tarpits to simply slow down requests from any IP address that seems to be abusing the system. This way, legitimate users from the same IP address can still carry on, albeit slower.

You have to be willing to shut off an IP address or IP address range despite the fact that you may be blocking innocent and upstanding users at the same time as the abusers. If your application is free, it may give you more freedom since there is no expected level of service and no contract, but you may want to guard yourself with a legal agreement.

In general, if your service is popular enough that someone wants to attack it, that's usually a good sign, so don't worry about it too much early on, but do stay ahead of it. You don't want the reason for your app's failure to be because users got tired of waiting on a slow server.

Your other option is to have the users register, so you can block by credentials rather than IP address when you spot abuse.

Comment: Make sure you upvote any useful answers to reward us for our time. Thank you.

Comment: +1 i was looking for a simple explanation.Is there any tutorial on this subject?If I understood correctly you need to restrict server acess based on logins. In my case (SAP with angular/cordova) upon registration a user is given an apikey that will be sent with each request to the webservice..I do want users to register once(always logged im when app starts),so re-route them when the app starts based on access(registered/not).my approach i am using sqlite to store client side info such as the apikey,name ect.. Is it also bad practice? if i were to encrypt these in db?

Comment: i do not want to use a server as a backend to store info,  im aiming at a simple webRTC app, users connect(p2p) and server brokers connection..so fter reading this im afraid the whole concept is bad practice if there is not way to store secure data client side on android..any advise is appreciated.. Thank you